# JMXTrans & WebLogic

Tags: weblogic

Have you ever used JMXTrans to monitor your weblogic server?

with the following config:

```
            {
              "servers" : [ {
                    "host": "a-pfg-admin.fr.net.intra",
                    "port":9091,
                    "url": "service:jmx:iiop://a-pfg-admin.fr.net.intra:9091/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime",
                    "username": "weblogic",
                    "password": "****",
                "queries" : [ {
                  "outputWriters" : [ {
                    "@class" : "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.KeyOutWriter",
                    "settings" : {
                      "outputFile" : "/tmp/jmxtrans1.txt",
                      "maxLogFileSize" : "10MB",
                      "maxLogBackupFiles" : 200,
                      "debug" : true,
                      "typeNames" : ["name"]
                    }
                  } ],
                  "obj" : "java.lang:type=Memory",
                  "resultAlias": "heap",
                  "attr" : [ "HeapMemoryUsage", "NonHeapMemoryUsage" ]
                }
                 ]
              } ]
            }
```

I got:

```
            [28 Oct 2011 16:39:54] [ServerScheduler_Worker-8] 1020012 ERROR (com.googlecode.jmxtrans.jobs.ServerJob:39) - Error
            java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
                    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:338)
                    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:248)
                    at com.googlecode.jmxtrans.util.JmxUtils.getServerConnection(JmxUtils.java:413)
                    at com.googlecode.jmxtrans.util.JmxConnectionFactory.makeObject(JmxConnectionFactory.java:30)
                    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
                    at com.googlecode.jmxtrans.jobs.ServerJob.execute(ServerJob.java:36)
                    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
                    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
            Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
                    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:645)
                    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
                    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:325)
                    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
                    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1886)
                    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1856)
                    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:257)
```

Even if i put in */etc/init.d/jmxtrans.sh*

```
            WL_HOME="/apps/WebLogic/10.3.2/AppServer"
            JMXTRANS_OPTS="-Djava.class.path=${JAVA_HOME}\lib\tools.jar;${WL_HOME}/server/lib/wlfullclient.jar -Djmx.remote.protocol.provider.pkgs=weblogic.management.remote"
            export JMXTRANS_OPTS;
```

Comment: Why do your directories have both "/" and "\"? If you're in a UNIX environment, ${JAVA_HOME}\lib\tools.jar should be ${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, setting a url on a Server object has no effect. This is probably an enhancement that could/should be made to the code.

I'm not sure why you are messing with the classpath, but that could also be part of your issue.

What JDK are you using?

Sorry, I don't have any experience with weblogic.

(I'm the author of jmxtrans)

Comment: I'm sending you an e-mail with a potential patch for weblogic.
Actually, a client should use a special setting to be connected to Weblogic.
I base my patch on the following paper: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/jmx/accessWLS.html

Answer (score 0):

From error it looks like its looking for java.naming.factory.initial environment property in weblogic.

I got this note from weblogic site - try this out
The property java.naming.factory.initial is used to specify how the InitialContext is created. To use WebLogic JNDI, you must always set the java.naming.factory.initial property to weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.